# What are good uses of OCaml packaged modules?

Tags: ocaml

The recent OCaml 3.12 introduces a [feature](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/distrib/ocaml-3.12/notes/Changes) of first-class packaged modules:

> **First-class packages modules.**
>
> - New kind of type expression, for packaged modules: `(module PT)`
> - New kind of expression, to pack a module as a first-class value: `(module MODEXPR : PT)`.
> - New kind of module expression, to unpack a first-class value as a module: `(val EXPR : PT)`.
> - PT is a package type of the form `S` or `S with type t1 = ... and ... and type tn = ...` (`S` refers to a module type).

Where can I find motivating examples or papers using this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe one of the canonical motivating examples is choosing between different structures implementing the same signature at based on information only available at runtime.

E.g., choosing between a hashtable and a balanced binary tree as an implementation of a Map.

There's some info at: https://forge.ocamlcore.org/docman/view.php/77/112/leroy-cug2010.pdf

I believe the OCaml design was influenced by a similar extension for SML by Claudio Russo - see e.g. "First-Class Structures for Standard ML" http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.34.8754&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: As far as I remember, Moscow ML, an SML implementation using caml-light as back-end, was the first to implement first-class modules. The appropriate section of Moscow ML's documentation refers to files mosml/examples/modules/{sieve.sml,array.sml,choice.sml,matrix.sml} from the distribution for examples.

Comment: @Pascal Nice reference for the examples.  That's the extension by Claudio that I mentioned.